# When loading dynamic component using Angular 2 RC6, component life cycle events are not invoked

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

When loading a component dynamically using the following method, the constructor for said component is invoked but none of the life cycle events are (eg. ngAfterViewInit or ngOnInit).

```
let component = getComponent(name);
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
this.componentRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
```

Is this the correct implementation for RC6, if so, could this be a bug?

**EDIT**

I have managed to fix this issue. FYI, it was to do with how I hooked up the above code into the parent components life cycle methods.

More information can be found [here](https://engineering-game-dev.com/2016/08/19/angular-2-dynamically-injecting-components/) and an example of the implementation can be found [here](https://engineering-game-dev.com/2016/08/19/angular-2-dynamically-injecting-components/).